# How do you make Windows Store App TextBlock Pressable?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, textblock

I see many win store apps have this but I couldn't figure out how it's done. Where basically I have TextBlock and it is pressable, by pressing on it something happens.  How do you achieve this?  Below is what I saw but it doesn't work.

```
 <Grid x:Name="TitleGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="TitlePressAnimation">
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" AutoReverse="True" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel x:ConnectionId='4' x:Name="TitlePanel" Orientation="Horizontal"                            Margin="120,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

open your app in blend. Click on textblock you have created and click on 'event handlers for selected item'. its located on the top righthand corner beside 'Name'.
now find a property called 'Tapped'. enter any name there such as 'tap' and doule click. this will create and open the function in c# page. Enter code which you want to be executed there.
here is the function created.

```
private void Tap(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add code here you want to execute when textblock is clicked.
    }
```